# Undo pull by date

Tags: git

I did some commits on my machine. These changes were not pushed on the server because the code was not completely debugged. I pulled the modifications done by other members of the project. These changes included branch merges. After this pull, I was not able to find the bugged modifications I was working on. I don't seem able to see them with gitk, git log or git branch-show.

Is there a way to undo the pull to go back to the version on my machine at 20:00 yesterday?
Or any way to get back my modification ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git reflog` to locate when your branch was updated.

Find the hash for the update you wish to revert back to and use `git reset --hard <SHA HERE>`